# create an order in Python Binance API with a stop Price

Tags: python, trading, binance, cryptocurrency

I am trying to create an order on the Binance API in Python with the following code:

```
exchange.create_order(
    symbol=symbol,
    type="stop_loss_limit",
    side="buy",
    amount=position,
    price=stop_loss_price,
    stopPrice=stop_loss_price,
)
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
create_order() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stopPrice'
```

The Binance API can not even register stopPrice as a variable yet all online documentation I can find on this shows 'stopPrice' as the variable in their examples.It looks to me that the documentation I have found is from an older version of the API and I just need to figure out what variable stopPrice is in the current version. If anyone can help me I would really apreciate it.

I tried using stopPrice as the variable because thats what the documentation I have found says yet the keyword will not register.

Answer (score 0):

Run Python interactively and say `help(exchange.create_order)`.  That will show you the parameter names (for any Python function, not just this one).